# Multiple controllers in one file, $broadcast/$on not working

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this in one controller.js file. In the template I have a set of nested divs.  Nested like this: ng-controller="OrderController"..., ng-controller="LineRowController"..., ng-controller="ToppingRowController"...

Here is the code in controller.js...

```
angular.module('AJM.OrderController', [])
.controller('LineRowController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.$on('hello', function () {
        console.log('heard hello!');
    });

}])
.controller('ToppingRowController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.$on('hello', function () {
        console.log('heard hello!');
    });

}])
.controller('OrderController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    console.log('Say hello...')
    $rootScope.$broadcast('hello');

}]);
```

**Additional note**: The real $broadcast is called in a $resource callback in the OrderController after some order data has loaded. So there is a small delay before that message is broadcast.

In the console I see "Say hello...", but never see either "heard hello!".

What am I missing? How can I be sure the $on hooks are set to hear the $broadcast? I don't think they are but I don't know how to control the sequence of controllers loading. Is this possible?

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: Were any of these the correct answer?

Comment: I ended up doing a service like GonchuB suggested. The sequence of the controllers in the file I believe is a factor as well as _on which DOM element I put the ng-controller attrib_. Had to fiddle around a lot with several parts before it all finally started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller that is broadcasting is being instantiated before the other two ever get a chance of subscribing to that event.

Maybe try something like this (although it's a very bad workaround, making timeout fake your waiting for rest of controllers to instantiate).

(edited to use service instead of timeout):

http://plnkr.co/edit/dT0OXYYW03mHB08JNToV?p=preview

I would suggest using a service to share "startup" information between controllers.

Comment: Bad workaround or not, this does work! I understand services and I could make a "Startup" service, but I'll still have the issue of needing to load data in the parent controller, and then when loaded, pass part of the data to the children. Won't I still have a timing issue using a service for this?

Comment: Is there some way to tell the parent controller when the last of it's children have loaded? At that point, the parent can load and send them their data by event or service or whatever.

Comment: I've updated my plunkr to show you how to use a service to pass this initial information. The other alternative would be using events, but this one, in my opinion, is prettier.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the order of operations are

- create order controller
- broadcast hello
- create line row controller
- create topping row controller

so the event is broadcast before the other 2 controllers are created.

See the console in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yx8P/)

```
console.log in the creation of each controller
```

That being explained, the code you wrote to broadcast and listen to events is correct, it is just a matter of timing. Typically $broadcast's are done based upon a user action, and the timing is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! Did you expect the "heard hello!"'s to show in console? They do not. Your fiddle demonstrates the controller load sequence, which makes sense, however the event is never caught/heard in the other controller $on's.

Comment: I did not expect to see it, think of it as talking on the phone to someone before they've answered.

Comment: Here's a thought: Should I $emit up from the child controllers to the parent to let it know when they're loaded? Then the parent can $broadcast the data to the children? Is that the idea?

Comment: If you're just looking to share some values during initial load, you can either inject a value or a service. $broadcast and $emit as I mentioned in my answer are more for notifications during the application's life-cycle. I typically use them for notification of user event's that need to be used application wide (user login/logout)

Comment: I put a console log in one of the child controller and it's never even loading.

Comment: That might be a different issue, you can see via the fiddle I created that they are executing.

Comment: Yeah it's another issue. I have the shared service setup with set/get but the other two controllers never instantiate. Only the parent.

Comment: You'll have to post the code. Another question would make sense, put a link to it here and I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, I think that your first two controllers are being fired first.

Try this:

**Edit:**

```
<div ng-app="AJM.OrderController" ng-view>
 <div ng-controller="OrderController">
    <div ng-controller="LineRowController">
        <div ng-controller="ToppingRowController"></div>
    </div>
 </div>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('AJM.OrderController', [])
    .controller('LineRowController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.$on('hello', function () {
            console.log('heard hello!');
        });

    }])
    .controller('ToppingRowController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        console.log('Say hello...')
        $rootScope.$broadcast('hello');

    }])
    .controller('OrderController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.$on('hello', function () {
            console.log('heard hello!');
        });

    }]);

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: This does do what you were looking for. The issue is simply the order of the controllers being instantiated in your HTML. Putting the broadcast in the inner-most `div` does the trick.